# VSTS Personal Access Token (PAT) vs OAUTH: different results of query

Tags: powershell, oauth, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, tfvc

I am using a PowerShell task to among others query a TFVC repository for changes after a certain point of time. To develop locally I created a PAT related to my user. In the release definition I enabled `Allow scripts to access OAUTH token`. If I now execute the release definition with the PAT respectively the OAUTH I get different results for existing changes (e.g. count is 1 for PAT and 0 for OAUTH). The queries are exactly the same:

`https://xxx.visualstudio.com/xxx/_apis/tfvc/changesets?searchCriteria.itemPath=$projectPath&searchCriteria.fromDate=$cloudVersionTimestampUTC&api-version=4.1`

Here the code to execute the query:

```
Write-Host "Get Request with the URI '$uri'"
if ($localDevelopment) {
    $GetResponse = Invoke-RestMethod `
        -Uri $uri `
        -Headers @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN)")) } 

    Write-Host "Requested last changes for local development: $($GetResponse | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"  
}
else {
    $GetResponse = Invoke-RestMethod `
        -Uri $uri `
        -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" } 
    Write-Host "Requested last changes: $($GetResponse | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
}
```

Does someone know why this is the case?

Thanks

Edits:
here the permissions of the `Project Collection Build Service (xxx)` account:
[image: permissions]

It is also important to mention that we don't use hosted agents but custom ones.

Comment: What's the permission of Project Collection Build Service (Xxx) account for that path?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT: thanks for your response. Please have a look on the edits.

Comment: What's the result if you try it with a new release definition? Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug to true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the different handling of timestamps when comparing PAT and OAUTH. As you can see I use the variable `$cloudVersionTimestampUTC` for `fromDate`. When I set the timestamp I did not add `Z` (like `MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss` instead of `MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ssZ`). PAT uses the given timestamp as UTC, OAUTH interprets it as local time (but I am not sure  of what - e.g. the default profile) when `Z` is not provided. This of course led to a different number of changesets (if the missing changeset was in the difference between UTC and local time).

In the end I had to be explicit about the timestamps. So what I did was to get the timestamp as string that was stored as tag in the Azure Resource and do the following:

```
$cloudVersionTimestampUTC = [DateTime]($cloudJobDefinition.Tags.'version-timestamp')
$cloudVersionTimestampUTC = (Get-Date -Date $cloudVersionTimestampUTC).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ssZ")
```

Then I was able to make the REST Call and retrieve the same number of changesets.